# I got this error when i'm tring to install libraries using requirements.txt file #Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, requirements.txt

Can't install google-api-core

virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt

ERROR: google-api-core 1.10.0 has requirement requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0, but you'll have requests 2.11.1 which is incompatible.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/treXH.png)

Comment: Is it possible to share `requirements.txt` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified `requests==2.11.1` in your requirements.txt file, and as the error states, google-api-core needs 2.18.0 or greater.

I suggest you upgrade the version of requests that your project is using and test that first before trying to add in google-api-core.

Either that or change requirements.txt so that it specifies `requests>=2.11.1` or perhaps use the `~=` "compatible" operator.